# rapsberry pi webserver(apache2) stops working after a few hours

Tags: apache, apache2, webserver, raspberry-pi

i cant connect to my raspberry pi web-server after a few hours and i need to turn it off and on again to make it work/

dose anyone know why this might be

it uses a USB WiFi dongle to connect to the internet
and it is being hosted at port 81

is it possible to at least write a script to make the pi reboot every 30 minute?

Answer (score 0):

The USB wifi dongle may draw too much power, and cause instability in the Raspberry pi. I had a similar problem with a USB sound card plugged into a RasPi.

You might try using a powered USB hub, or connect your Pi via Ethernet, to see if it shows the same behaviour.

There is also a (little used) watchdog timer on the Raspberry Pi. while enabled, some process on the raspi will need to inform the watchdog that everything is still ok. If the watchdog does not get told that everything is OK for too long, the watchdog will reboot the pi.

See http://blog.ricardoarturocabral.com/2013/01/auto-reboot-hung-raspberry-pi-using-on.html